# Is `clog` buffered?

Tags: c++, buffer, iostream

I have read in many places that `clog` is the same as `cerr`, except that `clog` is buffered and `cerr` is not. But I cannot see this behavior on my computer (Ubuntu 20.04, clang 9). Here is the code I use:

```
clog << "AA";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
clog << endl;
clog << "BB" << endl;
```

When I use `cout` instead of `clog`, I do not see anything in the first 3 seconds; then I immediately see AA and BB.

When I use `cerr` instead of `clog`, I see immediately AA, then after 3 seconds I see BB.

When I use `clog`, I see exactly as with `cerr` ---  immediately AA, then after 3 seconds I see BB.

If `clog` is buffered, shouldn't it behave like `cout`?

Is this a bug in my compiler?

Comment: *"I have read in many places..."* - Those places may not be very reliable.

Comment: Yes, [`std::clog` is buffered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog) but how this buffer behaves is implementation defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, `clog` is not supposed to be buffered, in fact the standard does not associate `clog` with `cout` in any way nor does it state tha `clog` should be buffered.

It does state that `cerr` and `clog` are both associated with `stderr`, so if there was to be some similarity in the behavior it should be between `clog` and `cerr`, which seems to be what you are experiencing.

As `stderr` is defined to be unbuffered it would be logical that `clog` is also unbuffered, but as this behavior isn't specified, it is not guaranteed to be always the case.

`cout` is associated with `stdout`, and its buffering settings are deppendent on the environment. Usually, for UNIX systems, it's line buffered.

### 29.4.3  Narrow stream objects   [narrow.stream.objects]

> #### ostream cout;
>
> 3 - *The object `cout` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stdout`, declared in `<cstdio>`(29.12.1).*

> #### ostream cerr;
>
> 4 - *The object cerr controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stderr`, declared in `<cstdio>`(29.12.1).*
>
> [...]

> #### ostream clog;
>
> 6 - *The object `clog` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stderr`, declared in `<cstdio>`(29.12.1).*